# Is there an inherit Textarea or Textbox Character Limit? NOT REFERRING to MaxLength

Tags: textarea, limit

So I have records being read from a database and placed into a **Textarea**. From there the textarea is being submitted by a form so it can write the text from the textbox to a file. I am putting my code below but this really isn't a question about code... it is a question about the limitations of a textarea. **Does anyone know if such limits exist?**

I have run over 25,000 40 Character lines through this code with no issues. I just tried to do 125,000 40 Character lines and even though the database is right, the output file the textbox was written to only has 69,000 of the 125,000. Weird right? I assumed if this was a buffer issue I would have seen an error.

DBTABLE(125,000 Rows) **--ReptRGn-->** Textarea(125,000 Rows?) **--POST-->** WriteToFile (69,000 Rows)

Textbox with a Repeat Region in it pulling all rows (single column) from a Database Table:

```
<textarea name="output2" cols="50" rows="5" id="output2"><% While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT ReadTable.EOF)) %><%=(ReadTable.Fields.Item("NUMBER40").Value) %><% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  If (NOT ReadTable.EOF) Then Response.Write(vbCr)
  ReadTable.MoveNext()
Wend
%></textarea>
```

Code to output the POSTed "output2" field into a file:

```
<%
function WriteToFile(FileName, Contents, Append)
on error resume next

if Append = true then
   iMode = 8
else 
   iMode = 2
end if
set oFs = server.createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oTextFile = oFs.OpenTextFile(FileName, iMode, True)
oTextFile.Write Contents
oTextFile.Close
set oTextFile = nothing
set oFS = nothing

end function

forty = Request.Form("output2")
WriteToFile "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\export\NUMBER40.txt", forty, False
%>
```

I did some research online but all I found was talk about MaxLength properties which is not this issue.

*Just as a side note... I started thinking while writing this... the application starts off by you pasting in the 125,000 rows into a textarea, which gets inserted into the database table. So that sort of ruins my theory that there is a limitation on the textarea.*

I would still like to know thoughts on what may be causing the data to stop being output to a file.